# Closing and opening serial port the right way

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, port

I am using the serial port to connect to a scale and get scale readings in a weighbridge windows app. Now I have coded in such a way that when I click the button to open and start receing the readings it starts to output the readings well and I use this code

```
Private Sub cmdOpen_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdOpen.Click
    comm.Parity = cboParity.Text
    comm.StopBits = cboStop.Text
    comm.DataBits = cboData.Text
    comm.BaudRate = cboBaud.Text
    comm.DisplayWindow = rtbDisplay
    comm.OpenPort()

    cmdOpen.Enabled = True
    cmdClose.Enabled = True
    cmdSend.Enabled = True

End Sub
Public Function OpenPort() As Boolean
    Try
        'first check if the port is already open
        'if its open then close it
        If comPort.IsOpen = True Then
            comPort.Close()
        End If

        'set the properties of our SerialPort Object
        comPort.BaudRate = Integer.Parse(_baudRate)
        'BaudRate
        comPort.DataBits = Integer.Parse(_dataBits)
        'DataBits
        comPort.StopBits = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(StopBits), _stopBits), StopBits)
        'StopBits
        comPort.Parity = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(Parity), _parity), Parity)
        'Parity
        comPort.PortName = _portName
        'PortName
        'now open the port
        comPort.Open()
        'display message
        _type = MessageType.Normal
        _msg = "Port opened at " + DateTime.Now + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
        '_msg = Environment.NewLine
        DisplayData(_type, _msg)
        'return true
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplayData(MessageType.[Error], ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
Public Sub ClosePort()
    If comPort.IsOpen Then
        _msg = "Port closed at " + DateTime.Now + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
        _type = MessageType.Normal
        DisplayData(_type, _msg)
        comPort.Close()
    End If
End Sub
  Private Sub comPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    'determine the mode the user selected (binary/string)
    Select Case CurrentTransmissionType
        Case TransmissionType.Text
            'user chose string
            'read data waiting in the buffer
            Dim msg As String = comPort.ReadExisting()
            'display the data to the user
            _type = MessageType.Incoming
            _msg = msg
            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, msg + "" + Environment.NewLine + "")
            Exit Select
        Case TransmissionType.Hex
            'user chose binary
            'retrieve number of bytes in the buffer
            Dim bytes As Integer = comPort.BytesToRead
            'create a byte array to hold the awaiting data
            Dim comBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(bytes - 1) {}
            'read the data and store it
            comPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes)
            'display the data to the user
            _type = MessageType.Incoming
            _msg = ByteToHex(comBuffer) + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, ByteToHex(comBuffer) + "" + Environment.NewLine + "")
            Exit Select
        Case Else
            'read data waiting in the buffer
            Dim str As String = comPort.ReadExisting()
            'display the data to the user
            _type = MessageType.Incoming
            _msg = str + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, str + "" + Environment.NewLine + "")
            Exit Select
    End Select
End Sub
Private Sub MonitorSP_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim SP As IO.Ports.SerialPort = DirectCast(sender, IO.Ports.SerialPort)
    Dim Data As String = SP.ReadLine
    'Remember this is in a background thread so you can not update the UI from here without using Me.Invoke
End Sub

Private Sub CloseSP()
    For Each selSP As IO.Ports.SerialPort In MonitorSP
        selSP.Close()
    Next
    MonitorSP.Clear()
End Sub
 Private Sub cmdClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdClose.Click
    'Comm is an instance of the class that contains the methods I showed above like Datareceived and so forth
    comm.ClosePort()
    comm.ClosePort()
    'SetControlState()
    SetDefaults()
End Sub
```

Now the challenge shows up when i try to close and re-open the port again when i close the port and wait for a few minutes and then attempt to reopen the port again it does not work (the readings do not show up on the scale). But when I close the port exit the form and then come back into the form and then open the port then the readings show up. My question is what can I do to open and close the port and the open it again without having to close the form or restart the app.

Comment: This code is a mess, clean it up first.